# How can I upload images in phone storage to Firebase at regular intervals using Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have already found a built-in app to take images at regular intervals using back camera of a phone and they are stored in internal storage of a phone. Can I create an app to automatically send those images at regular intervals to Firebase. Any guidelines to do this, will be highly appreciable

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking how to create an app that performs tasks as regular intervals?

Comment: Yes, What I want is to send images taken by phone camera at regular time intervals. This whole process of sending images to database at regular time interval, should be automated. I mean there shouldn't be any user interaction during the process. Thank You.

Comment: Ok. So writing code to perform a task at regular intervals is a fundamental programming concept. Once you understand that part, uploading a picture to Firebase is easy and covered in their [Getting Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files) guide. I would suggest googling how to code a Timer on  your android device and go from there.